# Displaying static text content with iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a svery simple requirement. I have a `<div>` tag within which I am displaying some text content.

I want to display the same text content in an `<iframe>`. What I am trying to achieve I have written below. Can anyone please help?

```
<b>
<div>This is a content which I want to display in iframe</div>
<iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe></b>
```

Comment: It looks like you dont understand how iframes work, I suggest reading up on it http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a **static HTML site**, create a new page with the content which you want to show and set the `src` of the `<iframe>`.

If it is a **dynamic page app (server side)**, create a `new page` or `handler` or `controller` (whatever applies) and set the `src` of the `<iframe>`.

These are the best and simplest ways to achieve what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks,If you could please answer my one more query,as you said i have a controller which has action "show" and takes some id. so now in src of iframe should i write this src="controllerName/action/id". ??

Comment: You may write like this - `src="/ControllerName/Action/ID"`. Please mark the answer as accepted (if it helped you) for other fellow StackOverFlow visitors.

Comment: Can you show it by code? I didn't get what you said.

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution which worked for me. Use **srcdoc** instead of **src**. It will display your static content inside iframe.

Below is the code:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<div>This is a content which I want to display in iframe</div>"></iframe>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found one more thing which is related to iframe which I think is interesting. 
You can auto fix the height and width of the `iframe` according to the content of the window.
All you need to do is to include the script written below and just pass the `id` of the `iframe`.

```
<iframe src="" width="100%" id="idIframe" onload="autoResize('idIframe');" ></iframe>     

<script>
function autoResize(id)
{
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;
    if(document.getElementById)
    {
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
} 
</script>
```