# How do i show the iframe as a string inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show a iframe which has to be treated as text rather than a screen. Is there any possibilities to achieve it using javascript or jquery.

**Html**

```
<div>
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/assy6s7x/)**

Comment: Why do you want to use an iframe and treat it as text

Comment: For what purpose you need iframe tag as text???

Comment: `<div>&lt;iframe&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</div>`??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389034/displaying-static-text-content-with-iframe

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thats what I am looking for but I need some javascript solution since i will be generating my content dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using JQuery `.text()`

```
var iframe = "<iframe></iframe>";
$(".test").text(iframe);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/assy6s7x/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : use `.text()` to put iframe as text

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#div1').text("<iframe></iframe>");
});
```

[**JSFIddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/assy6s7x/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you can either escape the brackets around the iframe tags or give the div and id or class and add a script like this.

this means you can define the content as standard html and have it converted to text a the time of loading

```
$('document').ready( function (){
   var div = $('#divAsText');
   div.text(div.html);
   div.html('');
}
```

the only downside to this is it may not pick up and convert the contents of the iframe